# How to programmatically add newly created node to a group in the Drupal Group Module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I am creating a management website. Super admin can create users. Users can create nodes. I need to know how to add that newly created nodes to the groups that users are in.

Answer (score 1):

The group that you want to say is called **roles** in Drupal.

For example: *When a user creates a node, this user has a role "editor". Then, the node was created by editor*.

You can modify the permission from this path. **Article: Create new content** */admin/people/permissions*.

[image]

Now, if you want to show the role in the content view, you have to edit the display view */admin/structure/types/manage/article/display* and show the author block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I need to know how to programmatically do this. I mean I need to do this using PHP function.

Comment: This function is provided by default in Drupal. Check the author options.

Comment: If you know how to find that code could you please provide a path?

Comment: I updated my answer, i hope that it solves your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But anyway, That is other thing than I wanted. I need answer like this. I mean I need an answer in PHP.

$type = $group->getGroupType()->id() . '-group_node-' . $node->getType();
$type = 'group_node-' . $node->getType();
$group->addContent($node, $type); See more - https://www.drupal.org/project/group/issues/2772623